# Gimp uses only one CPU when applying a Gaussian Blur

Tags: gimp, cpu-load, multi-core

If I use "Selective Gaussian Blur" in Gimp, only one CPU gets used. My PC has four.

Is there a way to tell Gimp to use all available CPUs?

Some operations take quite long, and this would reduce the time I need to wait.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multi-threading for GIMP filters will be introduced with GEGL support in [future releases](http://wiki.gimp.org/wiki/Roadmap). At present there is [work in progress to port Gaussian blur](http://wiki.gimp.org/wiki/Hacking:Porting_filters_to_GEGL) but this is not yet available.

As an alternative we can use the third-party plugin [G'MIC](http://registry.gimp.org/node/13469) which claims to at least partially support multi-threading. This plugin is available through the [gimp-plugin-registry](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gimp-plugin-registry) [image: Install gimp-plugin-registry] or newer version from **ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp**.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I will use the third party plugin. About "Wait for GEGL". I am not sure what will come first: GNU Hurd, Perl 7 or Gimp with full GEGL support. I hope you don't feel offended by this joke :-)

Comment: LOL *"Oh, and bring your sense of humor. Just in case."* from our [help]. :D